# Drag and drop images using jquery replacing them

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple example of drag and drop images using jquery:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag the W3Schools image into the rectangle:</p>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br>
<img id="drag1" src="imagenes/jugadores/1.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
<img id="drag2" src="imagenes/jugadores/2.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
<img id="drag3" src="imagenes/jugadores/3.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50" height="50">
</body>
</html>
```

This is working fine, but the problem I have is that it is always showing the first image I drop and what I want is to replace the current image with the last one dropped. Basically, updating in real time the image I drag and drop in the div id="div1".

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not JQuery, but ancient JavaScript.

And something else is happening here.

Whenever you drop an image on top of another, it's actually nested inside the previous one, like this:

```
<img..>
   <img.. />
</img>
```

You need to clear the area first, which means you need to grab hold of the parent, but I don't quite remember how that's supposed to work, but this does:

```
function drop(ev) {
   var dropzone = document.getElementById('div1');
   ev.preventDefault();
   var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
   if (dropzone.hasChildNodes())
      dropzone.innerHTML = "";
   dropzone.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

If you are interested in drag-drop using jquery I would recommend this:

[JQuery droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/)

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

   $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
   $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function() {
         alert( "dropped" );
      }
   });

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks a lot for your reply. I think I didn't explained myself properly, my bad :(. I will close this one has done, cause you are solving my question. Thanks!